# File not found.... Error On Wordpress Permalink change IIS Server

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, iis-8

I have been working on a WordPress website using IIS windows server. when I changed my permalinks to anything except post id and try to visit any page other than homepage I get an error

> No input file specified.

I am using IIS server to host my files and database. I have tried several solutions which includes resetting permalinks, configuring php.ini file, configuring web.config file but I got no results even the link remains same. My web.config file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.php" />
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="Default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The website is [stage.cirasync.com](http://stage.cirasync.com)
Homepage is working fine while other link give the error above.

Any suggestions to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this config :

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>

Comment: remove aboove lines